# C++ - Method/Member access

Tags: c++, compilation, private, public

We all know that private methods and members are only accessable inside the class, same way that protected methods and members are accessable inside the class and classes that derived from that class. But where is the «access control» of this? Does the «access control» happen in compile time, or does the compiler add addional machine code that controls that in runtime?

Can I create a class like this:

```
class Print  
{
        public: 
                void printPublic();

        private:
                void printPrivate();
};

int main() 
{
        Print print;  

        print.printPublic() // Change this to printPrivate() after compiling the code

        return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

And then after compiling the code edit the machine code to call `printPrivate()` instead of `printPublic()` method without error?

Comment: So your asking if access control is built into the binary or if it is purely something that is checked at compile time?

Comment: Upvoted as this question is well written, if a little peculiar.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The «access control» happen at compile time and **only** for c++ code. you even not need edit the machine code - you can easy call private methods from assembly language - so this demonstrate that this is only for c++ restriction. and of course no any additional machine code that controls that in run-time - this at all impossible control who call method.

simply demo . note function names, how it mangled depended from x86 or x64 compiling and from compiler probably - my demo for *CL* compiler and x64 platform bat it can be easy changed to x86 or other compiler

c++ code

```
class Print  
{
public: 
    void printPublic();

private:
    void printPrivate();
};

// must be not inline or referenced from c++ code or will be droped by compiler!
void Print::printPrivate()// thiscall
{
    DbgPrint("%s<%p>\n", __FUNCTION__, this);
}
void Print::printPublic()// thiscall
{
    DbgPrint("%s<%p>\n", __FUNCTION__, this);
}

extern "C"
{
    // stub impemeted in asm
    void __fastcall Print_printPrivate(Print* This);
    void __fastcall Print_printPublic(Print* This);
};


    Print p;
    //p.printPrivate();//error C2248
    p.printPublic();
    Print_printPrivate(&p);
    Print_printPublic(&p);
```

and asm code (for *ml64*)

```
_TEXT segment 'CODE'

extern ?printPrivate@Print@@AEAAXXZ:proc
extern ?printPublic@Print@@QEAAXXZ:proc

Print_printPrivate proc
    jmp ?printPrivate@Print@@AEAAXXZ 
Print_printPrivate endp

Print_printPublic proc
    jmp ?printPublic@Print@@QEAAXXZ 
Print_printPublic endp

_TEXT ENDS
END
```

also note for x86 only that all c++ methods use *thiscall* calling convention - first parameter *this* in *ECX*  register and next in stack as for *__stdcall* - so if method have no parameters (really one *this* ) we can use *__fastcall* for asm function as is, and if exist parameters we need push *EDX* to stack in assembler stub. for x64 no this problem - here only one calling convention, but all this already not related to main question.

---

example for x86 code with extra params, for show how transform *__fastcall* to *__thiscall*

```
class Print  
{
public: 
    void printPublic(int a, int b)// thiscall
    {
        DbgPrint("%s<%p>(%x, %x)\n", __FUNCTION__, this, a, b);
    }

private:
    void printPrivate(int a, int b);
};

// must be not inline or referenced from c++ code or will be droped by compiler!
void Print::printPrivate(int a, int b)// thiscall
{
    DbgPrint("%s<%p>(%x, %x)\n", __FUNCTION__, this, a, b);
}

extern "C"
{
    // stub impemeted in asm
    void __fastcall Print_printPrivate(Print* This, int a, int b);
    void __fastcall Print_printPublic(Print* This, int a, int b);
};
        Print p;
        //p.printPrivate(1,2);//error C2248
        p.printPublic(1, 2);
        Print_printPrivate(&p, 1, 2);
        Print_printPublic(&p, 1, 2);
```

and asm

```
.686p

_TEXT segment

extern ?printPublic@Print@@QAEXHH@Z:proc
extern ?printPrivate@Print@@AAEXHH@Z:proc

@Print_printPrivate@12 proc
    xchg [esp],edx
    push edx
    jmp ?printPrivate@Print@@AAEXHH@Z 
@Print_printPrivate@12 endp

@Print_printPublic@12 proc
    xchg [esp],edx
    push edx
    jmp ?printPublic@Print@@QAEXHH@Z
@Print_printPublic@12 endp

_TEXT ends

end
```

Answer (score 2):

Once you've fiddled around with the machine code, you're no longer compiling C++, but you're programming directly in machine code.

Your question is therefore somewhat moot.

You can regard the access specifiers as being essentially compile time directives, but note that the compiler can make optimisation choices based on them. In other words, it could be either. The C++ standard doesn't have to say anything about this either.

Answer (score 1):

The «access control» happen at compile time